# How do I run Separate Mining Devices With BFGMINER?

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, bfgminer

I have 2 devices plug into my computer.
The 1st device is the USB block erupter.
The 2nd device is the BFL machine.

When I run the BFGminer, I only want one device to mine at one pool and the other device to mine at another pool?

How do I do that using BFGminer?

Answer (score 1):

I do this by running two copies of BFGMiner and using the --scan parameter to specify which devices are used by each miner.  In my case, I have a bunch of USB Block Erupters and a BE Cube.

One BFGMiner specifies '--scan none' and '--http-port 8330' to support the BE Cube (which connects over the local network).

The other BFGMiner specifies '--scan-serial erupter:all' to support the USB erupters.

This is also useful when the devices vary in hash power.  I set the USB erupters to difficulty 4 while the BE Cube is set to difficulty 16.